# JQuery Raphael Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, raphael

I've created a pie chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/amakkawy/cLRYq/

```
r.customAttributes.segment = function(x, y, r, a1, a2) {
    var flag = (a2 - a1) > 180,
    clr = (a2 - a1) / 360;
    a1 = (a1 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
    a2 = (a2 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
    return {
        path: [["M", x, y], ["l", r * Math.cos(a1), r * Math.sin(a1)], ["A", r, r, 0, +flag, 1, x + r * Math.cos(a2), y + r * Math.sin(a2)], ["z"]],
        fill: "url(http://www.trendir.com/outdoors/landscape-forms-shade-35-umbrella-under.jpg)"
    };
};
```

and unsure how to set this code up to have a different image/fill for each segment.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This was a really great first question. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks - Not quite sure how to separate the segments so I can fill them separately. Saw a similar post relating to size of each segment ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773080/update-pie-slice-size-in-raphael-pie-chart?rq=1 ) but wasn't sure how to apply to fill.

Answer (score 0):

you can try out with my code

```
 r.customAttributes.segment = function (x, y, r, a1, a2) {
            var flag = (a2 - a1) > 180,
                    clr = (a2 - a1) / 360;
            a1 = (a1 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
            a2 = (a2 % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
            return {
                path: [
                    ["M", x, y],
                    ["l", r * Math.cos(a1), r * Math.sin(a1)],
                    ["A", r, r, 0, +flag, 1, x + r * Math.cos(a2), y + r * Math.sin(a2)],
                    ["z"]
                ],
                fill: "hsb(" + clr + ", .75, .8)"
            };
        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jophine/E8EU8/